# wrong usage of "cool" when compared to "cold"

Tags: word-usage

Is it totally wrong to say **"it is really *cool* outside"** instead of saying **"it is really *cold* outside"**?

Answer (score 1):

[Cool](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cool?s=t)

> **cool** [kool]
>
> **adjective**, cooler, coolest.
>
> 1. moderately cold; neither warm nor cold
>
>    *a rather cool evening.*
> 2. not excited; calm; composed; under control
>
>    *to remain cool in the face of disaster.*
>
> *Slang.*
>
> a. great; fine; excellent
>
> *a real cool comic.*
>
> b. characterized by great facility; highly skilled or clever
>
> *cool maneuvers on the parallel bars.*
>
> c. socially adept
>
> *It's not cool to arrive at a party too early.*

[Cold](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cold?s=t)

> **cold** [kohld]
>
> **adjective, colder, coldest.**
>
> 1. having a relatively low temperature; having little or no warmth
>
>    *cold water; a cold day.*
> 2. feeling an uncomfortable lack of warmth; chilled
>
>    *The skaters were cold.*
> 3. not affectionate, cordial, or friendly; unresponsive
>
>    *a cold reply; a cold reception.*

They can be interchangeable in some situations but cool and cold have their own temperatures. Cool is in-between Cold and warm. Cold is in-between Cool and Freezing.

Comment: so, if its moderately cold outside, does it mean saying , "it is really cool outside" is correct?

Comment: @user3701803 Yes that is correct

Comment: @user3701803 Cool can also be interchangeable with chilly.

Answer (score 1):

**It is OK to say "It is really cool outside" instead of "It is really cold outside."**

For example, suppose it is snowing, and crisp and beautiful, and it all makes you feel great. You say "It is really cool outside!"  (Sentence 1)

But it is also very cold, so you could say "It is really cold outside!"  (Sentence 2)

To return to what I think is your literal question: It depends on the situation.

"Take your sweater; it's really cool outside."  It is May in Virginia, and the high is going to be 60 degrees F. (It's been over 85 every day for the last week.)  (Sentence 3)

"Wear a sweater under your parka, and wear your fleece pants; it's really cold outside'.  It is January in Virginia, and the high is going to be 5 degrees F. (Sentence 4)

Sentence 1 uses the slang meaning of **cool**: "to express approval or admiration"  Dictionary.com (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cool)

In Sentence 3, **cool** means:  "Moderately cold; lacking in warmth" *Webster's New Collegiate Dictionary* (hard copy)

In Sentence 2 and 4, **cold** means: "Decidedly below the normal temperature; gelid; frigid"  *Webster's New Collegiate Dictionary*

What is cool and what is cold is at least partially subjective.  A Brit might find a 60 degree day in May delightfully warm.  A researcher at Amundsen-Scott Base at South Pole would not find 5 degrees F in January cold.